# Acrobat Reader would like to re-design my PDF file

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am making my own PDF parser/maker. For the moment I am able to parse existing PDF file and even make a new PDF based on the early parsed data. But the problem is that when I open a new PDF file (made by my parser/maker) Adobe Reader would like to re-design the document (when I close document Reader suggest me to store "changed document"). Such problem I had earlier when my documents had incorrect internal structure. But with latest version of my parser I can not see any problem in file structure and need to ask a "PDF gurus". I should say that I made a PDF structure checking via online PDF checking tool and also inside Adobe Reader Pro. Also all existing PDF parsers that I found can parse my PDF without any problems. The only problem I have is with Adobe Reader.

So, I have two files:

1. [Initial PDF file](http://www.strozhevsky.com/free_docs/_initial.pdf);
2. [Secondary PDF file, made by my tool](http://www.strozhevsky.com/free_docs/_secondary.pdf);

In fact the "secondary PDF" is a simple copy of initial PDF with slightly changed internal PDF structure. Of course, all "xref" offsets also were changed. Both files are very simple and have only 18 internal objects most of them are fonts objects. The "second PDF" is the PDF considered as buggy by Adobe Reader.

Also would be highly appreciated if someone could give me a link to any Reader-specific rules for PDF file (if you have any).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries in the cross reference table in _secondary.pdf are **only 19 bytes** long and not **20 bytes** as expected:

> Each entry shall be exactly 20 bytes long, including the end-of-line marker.

You're not the only one producing such files, that's why most of all readers/parsers have a fallback integrated or ignore the 20 bytes count at all.

Anyhow, this file should be marked as corrupted (what Acrobat does) because it requires to manually parse the cross reference table or the complete file. In this situation a parser is not able to use the fixed entry size to directly jump to the object offset definitions in the cross reference table.

Comment: Thank you very much, Jan! So small problem (one byte difference), but so much time I spent working on it. Hope others will miss my error.